# Commenting several lines in Overleaf, without numerical pad, FR keyboard

Tags: overleaf, comments, shortcut

In order to comment/uncomment quickly several lines, Overleaf shortcut is:

> Ctrl + /

I can't use it on my laptop without a numerical pad, with French keyboard with slash key among the capitals (on top of :); `Ctrl + Shift + /` does not work for me. What else could work?

Comment: What keyboard is your laptop. On US Intl. you have a forwardslash on the main keyboard.

Comment: if / is not on your main keyboard (it is under `?` on my UK one) then you should still be able to use ctrl in combination with whatever combination you use to get / shouldn't you?

Comment: you may be better asking overleaf support they must have many users with that keyboard, and this has probably already come up. (It's hard to test on a different keyboard layout what would work)

Comment: Given the alternative proposed by the OP (`Ctrl + Shift + /`) I guess he is using a French AZERTY keyboard (or something close). According to [this cheat sheet](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/overleaf-keyboard-shortcuts/qykqfvmxdnjf), the alternative is `Ctrl + Shift + 7` (the one in the top line, not on the numerical pad).

Comment: @KersouMan that looks like a good call, post as answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for it to be more visible than my comment:

According to the [cheat sheet](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/overleaf-keyboard-shortcuts/qykqfvmxdnjf) provided by Overleaf support team, the alternative for quick comment/uncomment in case of missing `/` key is `Ctrl + Shift + 7` (the one in the top line of the keyboard) or `Ctrl + ß` if ß is available on your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac it is: cmd + shift + ß

Comment: The ß is only available on a German keyboard though.